# Textboxes don't work Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am not able to have a user input in a textbox when click it both in the Emulator and in windows phone device. I have deleted all the textboxes and replace them with new ones without any special preferences and still don't work. I have implemented the whole interface of my application and need help to solve this issue and start playing with the server connection. Also the rest of the controls all work properly. Please any ideas?

[This is the corresponding interface of the code I am posting below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqY2O.png)

This is my mainpage.xaml code: If you need anything else please let me know.

```
    <controls:ViewPage
x:Class="Menu_and_Topbar_app__Windows_Phone_8._1_3.MainPage"
xmlns:controls="using:Menu_and_Topbar_app__Windows_Phone_8._1_3.Controls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Menu_and_Topbar_app__Windows_Phone_8._1_3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#FF250D5C">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="5.857,6.897,8.265,12.783" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="620.32" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="385.878" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="0.309"/>
        </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>

        <Pivot Name="MyPivot" IsEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True">
            <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  FontSize="37" SelectionHighlightColor="#FF898888" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

            <PivotItem x:Name="PivotItem1"  Header="Sign In" IsEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="496" Margin="18,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" IsTapEnabled="True" IsRightTapEnabled="True">
                    <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="64,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Source="/Menu and Topbar app (Windows Phone 8.1)3/Pictures/logo.png" Visibility="Visible" />
                    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Log In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,409,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click_1"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,113,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username or Email:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>


                    <HyperlinkButton Content="Sign Up for SCP?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13.333" NavigateUri="http://scponline.azurewebsites.net/Home/LoginPartialView"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Remember me?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,137,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275" GotFocus="textBox_GotFocus" AllowDrop="True" />

                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>


            <PivotItem x:Name="PivotItem2" Header="Sign Up" >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="496" Margin="18,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311">
                    <Button Content="Sign Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,437,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,126,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="username@mail.com" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="276" FontSize="17.593" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="0.9"/>
                        </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="***********" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="276" TextChanged="textBox2_TextChanged" FontSize="17.593" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="0.9"/>
                        </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="64,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Source="/Menu and Topbar app (Windows Phone 8.1)3/Pictures/logo.png"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,232,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="textBlock1_SelectionChanged" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,250,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="276" TextChanged="textBox2_TextChanged" FontSize="17.593" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="0.9"/>
                        </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBox>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,292,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="textBlock1_SelectionChanged" FontSize="16"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="276" TextChanged="textBox2_TextChanged" FontSize="17.593" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="0.9"/>
                        </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>

        </Pivot>


    </ScrollViewer>



</Grid>
```

Comment: Define "don't work". What is the codebehind, desired output, actual output etc.

Comment: remove IsTapEnabled property of pivots

Comment: Hi and thank for you response. Don't work means when I run the application and click on the textbox I am not able to insert a text. On textbox click nothing happens. There is no code behind that has to do with the textbox. I removed the Is TapEnabled property but nothing changed.

Comment: i dont see a problem in my emulator (https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=775B6FDBA32D0BE2!7117&authkey=!AHtw3Sc4_74ZxR8&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng).. can you explain the issue properly again?